# z-index not active

Tags: css, z-index

I have a small example, with two adjacent divs with a background image. This divs are tiles in a tile based editor. I want to place an image into the first div and change the position of the image, so that the image overlaps both divs (see http://jsfiddle.net/WRZJe/16/). I've set the z-index of all divs and I've set the z-index of the image. The position attribute for both, divs and image is set to absolute:

```
<body id="exploration-body">
    <div class="dungeon-container" style="left: 1040px; top: 720px;">
        <div class="dungeon-canvas-full-screen" id="dungeon_canvas">
            <div style="top: -720px; left: -1040px; 
                   background-position: -82px -162px;" class="show-tile">
                <img id="token-1" class="token-img"        
                   src="1.png" alt="token1" style="top: 0px; left: 40px">
            </div>            
            <div style="top: -720px; left: -960px; background-position: -82px -162px;" class="show-tile">
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the relevant css-code:

```
.dungeon-container {
    position: absolute;
}

.show-tile {
    background-image: url("stone_dungeon.png");
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
}

.token-img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

As the z-index of the images is higher then both divs, I expect the image to be drawn in front of both divs. But page behaves like no z-indexes where given. The image hides behind the second div and would be in front of every div before the image containing div.

What might cause the browser (I've tested Safari and FF) to ignore the given z-index?

Update: I've added a screenshot from the actual application (http://robitzki.de/zindex.png) that shows, that the image moves behind those divs, that are placed after the containing div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `div.show-tile` (which are all siblings) creates an own stacking context! Child elements remain in the stacking context of the parent, thus your `img` will be hidden if it is adjacent to a div which has a higher z-index as the images parent div. *The z-index of the image itself (=child) does not matter in this case*.

In order to have the image overlap all the divs, the cleanest solution would be to *not* put it into one of the divs, but put it separately as a sibling to your `.show-tile` divs and give it the highest z-index.

Alternatively, you could omit your absolute positioning on the divs - this would make the `img` having it's position depend on `#dungeon_canvas`.

If you cannot do so, you have to assure that the div which holds your image always has the highest z-index.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation helped a lot. I think adding a little bit to the z-index of the image containing div could be a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the second div before the first one so that it comes before the img tag

```
<body id="exploration-body">
    <div class="dungeon-container" style="left: 1040px; top: 720px;">
        <div class="dungeon-canvas-full-screen" id="dungeon_canvas">
            <div style="top: -720px; left: -960px; background-position: -82px -162px;" class="show-tile">
            </div>            
            <div style="top: -720px; left: -1040px; background-position: -82px -162px;" class="show-tile">
                <img id="token-1" class="token-img" src="http://dungeonpilot.com/assets/tokens/1.png" alt="token1" style="top: 0px; left: 40px">
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WRZJe/17

If you can move the img tags out of the divs and position them using similar coordinates to the divs then the following will produce the desired display

```
<body id="exploration-body">
    <div class="dungeon-container" style="left: 1040px; top: 720px;">
        <div class="dungeon-canvas-full-screen" id="dungeon_canvas">
            <img id="token-1" class="token-img" src="http://dungeonpilot.com/assets/tokens/1.png" alt="token1" style="top: -720px; left: -1000px" />
            <img id="token-2" class="token-img" src="http://dungeonpilot.com/assets/tokens/1.png" alt="token1" style="top: -720px; left: -930px" />
            <div style="top: -720px; left: -960px; background-position: -82px -162px;" class="show-tile">
            </div>            
            <div style="top: -720px; left: -1040px; background-position: -82px -162px;" class="show-tile">
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WRZJe/20

Comment: That would only solve the example problem, not the fact that the z-index is ignored. What if I would like to place a image into the first div as well and want to overlap it both divs? But thank you for having a look at it! :-)

Comment: As the editor is tile based, this makes resizing a whole map very convenience. The actual problem occurs only, when dragging a token on the map to an other tile. The workaround I will implement (if I don't find a solution) is, to move the image from the source div to the container div (with appropriate position fixing) when the user starts dragging the token and then to move the token into the target div, when the user drops the token.

Answer (score 1):

Because the second `.show-tile` has a higher `z-index` than the image, the image will be cut off

try this:

```
.dungeon-container {
    position: absolute;
}

.show-tile {
    background-image: url("stone_dungeon.png");
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    /*z-index: 5;*/
}

.token-img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRZJe/22/) to see it work

Comment: This works, but I fail to understand, why it works. The z-index of .token-img in my example was 50, and the z-index of .show-tile was 5, so I thought .token-img has to closer to the screen and thus in front of .show-tile. What am I'm missing?

Comment: Because the second .show-tile has a higher z-index than the image, the image will be cut off

Comment: @Mark the second .show-tile has z-index 5 and the image was z-index 50, so the image was having the higest z-index property.

Comment: the second .show-tile is a new stacking order, so the image in the first can never be "closer to you".Child elements remain in the stacking context of the parent

Comment: I will try, if getting rid of the z-index for the tile divs could be a solution. It would be clearly the easiest solution to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Now do easily this as like this **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WRZJe/31/)**

**Html code**

```
<div class="main-container"> 
    <div class="pic-1 pic-5"></div>
    <div class="pic-1 pic-3"></div>
    <div class="pic-1 pic-2"></div>
    <div class="pic-1 pic-4"></div>
    <img src="http://dungeonpilot.com/assets/tokens/1.png" alt="" class="pic-change">
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.pic-1 {
    background-image: url("http://dungeonpilot.com/assets/stone_dungeon.png");
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-position: -3px -3px;
}
.pic-2{
    clear:left;
}
.pic-change{
    position:absolute;
    left:40px;
    top:40px;
    z-index:3;
}
.main-container{
    position:relative;

}
.pic-4{
    z-index:4;

}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WRZJe/31/)***